# Transitive dependencies breaks "Go to declaration" in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, react-native

I have an Android React Native project with third-part modules.

Android Studio fails to jump to the right dependency:

- `com.facebook.react.LifecycleState` points to `react-native-0.19.0`
- `com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager` points to `react-native-0.35.0`

[image: Mouse over on imports]

As my app depends on 0.35.0, I expect an error to be raised on the `com.facebook.react.LifecycleState` import (since class definition has moved between 0.19 et 0.35)

My app also depends on a module that depends on 0.19.0 and for a reason I do not understand yet, Android Studio pulls down the import and allow me to jump to the source of 0.19.0

This is an awful fallback, not even consistent with Gradle `./gradlew -q dependencies`

**This behavior makes errors very difficult to spot and fix. What can I do about it?**

Answer (score 0):

Try importing `com.facebook.react.common.LifecycleState`.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not my point : I want to fix Android Studio's behavior

Comment: How can you expect it to work properly since you importing something that's in not even in 0.35? Android Studio found it in other place- you're importing outdated software so it's from old RN module. I don't consider it a bug.

Comment: Android Studio should not be aware of the existence of 0.19.0. What about imports that are shared by 0.35.0 and 0.19.0? Android Studio just flips a coin to find the source code?